# Calculating the SNR of a video

Tags: image-processing

I have a video and I want to calculate the SNR for it.

I know how to do it with an audio signal, but with a video I don't have a clue. I'm using SCILAB for the analysis.

Comment: Do you have the noise-free video as reference?

Comment: no I don't have a noise-free video

Comment: is there a way to do it without the reference video?  how do you do it with audio?